# How do I leverage query and route parameters in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js

Is there a possibility that Next.js does route matching with these routes?

`/items?search=foo`

`/items/:id`

I could do it in another way but I must respect the specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Next.js does matching with those routes.

Keep in mind, Next.js does file system based routing, so you need to structure your routes as follows:

```
 project
 ┣ node_modules
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┗ items
 ┃   ┗ [id].js
 ┃   ┗ index.js
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
```

`[id].js` will match `/items/:id`, you can access the id in the component by doing:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { id } = router.query
```

`index.js` will match `/items?search=foo`

You can get the query param by doing:

```
const router = useRouter();
const query = router.query
```

The `query` object will look something like `{ search: foo }`

Comment: Works fine, thanks for your time! Alex :)